# Equivalent of TinyXML for JSON in C++?

Tags: c++, json

Is there any small C++ JSON decoder? It should work under both GCC and Visual Studio. It doesn't need to support encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've had success with [jsoncpp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsoncpp/)